# JQuery.getJSON method is not working

Tags: jquery, json, google-api, getjson, freebase

I am just trying to get a JSON file and when it is read, trying to show an alert.

My code is like below
http://jsbin.com/winogafoqa/edit?html,js,console

```js
$url = "http://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/text/en/bob_dylan?jsoncallback=?";

document.onload(
  function() {
    $.getJSON($url, function(result) {
      alert("success");
    });
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

But I am not getting any alert messages.
Am I missing something?

Comment: clearly throws errors for me. Please post relevant code in question. We shouldn't have to go off site to see your code. Questions should be self contained and use demos as add-ons

Comment: If you paste the url in a browser you get this: `{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"sslRequired","message":"SSL is required to perform this operation."}],"code":403,"message":"SSL is required to perform this operation."}}`

Comment: google to be queried wants an ssl connection. So change the URL to https:// . Check my answer for further details

Answer (score 1):

to download that JSON is required an ssl connection. You will need to include jQuery, and use it correctly.

`$(document).ready`... is the correct syntax.

You must query the right url, which is: `https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/text/en/bob_dylan?jsoncallback=?` (note: https)

Check this working example: https://jsfiddle.net/s1f56o54/2/